# Database error when www prefix is used

Tags: database, focus-lab-master-config

I am using a version of the Focus Labs Master Config setup and I am getting a database error when using the www. prefix in front of the URL. This is a problem that I haven't run into before. Anyone have any thoughts?

You can see the issue at http://denvillechamber.com. Obviously add the www prefix to recreate the error.

Answer (score 3):

This is because the master config changes database configurations based on the value of `$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']`, and you likely have "denvillechamber.com" as your value, which is not the same as "www.denvillechamber.com".

Your site should not be accessible at both **www** and **non-www** locations - one should redirect to the other.

Put this in your `.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.denvillechamber\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://denvillechamber.com/$1 [L,R=301]
```

Should fix your problem.